# SQL Query to get top 10 records

Tags: sql-server

I need to display max 9th record from top 10 records in Sql Server.

Here is my query to select top 10 records.

```
   select top(10) * from Employee
```

Comment: Huh? `select top(9) ...` How do you order the rows?

Comment: Always add an `order by` to your `top` queries, except you want random data.

Comment: with in that 10 records need to get 9th record

Comment: What do you mean saying max of 9th record? If you need the top 9 records as Tim wrote above you write select top(9)...

Answer (score 3):

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EmployeeID) AS RowNum
    FROM   Employee
)
SELECT * FROM MyCTE WHERE RowNum = 9
```